# Free multiple dynamically created frames in a loop

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.3-rio

I have a program where on one of the forms I need to dynamically create an unspecified number of frames (determined by the number of records after a database search) at runtime. I have done this using a for loop, and each newly created frame is assigned a new name like so:

```
for K:=1 to qryAeroAir.RecordCount do
      begin
        frmFlightDisplay:=TfrmFlightDisplay.Create(frmBook);
        frmFlightDisplay.Name:='frmFlightDisplay'+IntToStr(K);
        frmFlightDisplay.Parent:=pnlBookingDisplay;
        // Rest of code for frame properties
      end;
```

This seems to work fine, however later on in the program I need to free or destroy these frames before creating new ones (with the same sort of loop) and this is where I am having a problem.

```
for I:=1 to qryAeroAir.RecordCount do
    begin
    TfrmFlightDisplay(FindComponent('frmFlightDisplay'+IntToStr(I))).Free;
    end;
```

The above code gives me an error 'Frame with the name frmFlightDisplay1' already exists, which leads me to believe that the frames are not actually being destroyed. Is there any other way to free or destroy all of the frames which will prevent this from occurring?

Comment: Are you sure the error isn't "A *component* named frmFlightDisplay1 already exists"?

Comment: What is `qryAeroAir`? If it is database query are you sure that it returns the same amount of records at time of freeing your frames as it did at time of their creation? Or is it perhaps some kind of a list in which case it would be better to reverse the order when freeing your objects so that you start from last on the list and move toward the first on the list. Why is this necessary? Well if you remove first object on the list position of other objects gets shifted by one so your loop would end up skipping every second object.

Comment: @SilverWarior: That doesn't apply here, since the components are *named* `frmFlightDisplay1`, `frmFlightDisplay2`, and so on. Removing the first one doesn't rename the second one. But, as I say in my A, referring to a sequence of components using string names is "strange", and had this been done properly, using a list, your remark would of course be accurate.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand Proboably not. But it is possible that OP is updating `qryAeroAir` or `qryAeroAir.RecordCount` with some code that he hasn't shown us, which could lead to the same problem. Hence the reason why I mentioned this any way even thou the chances for such scenario are ow.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand my mistake, you are correct the error is  "A component named frmFlightDisplay1 already exists"

Comment: @SilverWarior the qryAeroAir is an ADOQuery relating to my database, and no changes were made to the query from the time of creation to the time of freeing, so the same amount of records should be shown in both cases. I understand though that my method is quite flawed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managing dynamically created objects using string manipulation is fragile and not very performant.

A much better approach, IMHO, is to store the frames in an object list. Declare, in your form class, a private field (uses `Generics.Collections`)

```
private
  FFrames: TObjectList<TfrmFlightDisplay>;
```

and create and destroy it with the form:

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFrames := TObjectList<TfrmFlightDisplay>.Create(True {owns objects});
end;

procedure TForm1.FormDestroy(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFrames.Free;
end;
```

Then, when you create a new frame, you put it in this list, which will then own it:

```
procedure TForm1.btnAddFlightDisplayClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  frm: TfrmFlightDisplay;
begin
  frm := TfrmFlightDisplay.Create(nil);
  try
    frm.Parent := Self;
    // other code settings properties of frm
  except
    frm.Free;
    raise;
  end;
  FFrames.Add(frm); // transfer of ownership
end;
```

To free all frames, simply remove them from the list. Since the list owns the frames, this will free the frame objects:

```
procedure TForm1.btnClearClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FFrames.Clear;
end;
```

## What's wrong with your code?

But I haven't explained what is wrong with your code.

My *guess* is that

1. the actual error message is "A component named frmFlightDisplay1 already exists",
2. the exception happens not when you try to remove frames, but when you try to add them again, and
3. the code blocks adding and removing the frames aren't in methods of `frmBook`.

If my guesses are correct, the problem is that you clearly let the frames be owned by `frmBook` (the argument given to the frame's constructor), but `FindComponent` is a shorthand for `Self.FindComponent` and if this isn't run in a method of `frmBook`, then `Self` isn't `frmBook`. Therefore, `FindComponent` will return `nil` and `Free` will have no effect. (Fortunately, `X.Free` is safe even if `X` is `nil`.)

Consequently, a quick fix to your problem would be to write `frmBook.FindComponent` instead.

Comment: The call to `FFrames.Add(frm)` should be inside the `try..except`, so that in case `Add()` raises an exception, the `frm` can still be freed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: That is assuming an exception in `Add` implies ownership hasn't been transferred. Is that a documented guarantee? (My reasoning is that since a leak is less severe than the opposite issue (freeing the object which *has* been added to the list), it is safer to do it like this, until I can read some documentation guaranteeing that exception => no transfer of ownership.) In any case, an exception here is exceedingly unlikely.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand thank you, your solution is perfect. And thanks for your explanation as to why what I have tried is does not completely work in this case, I am still quite a novice (this program is for my final year Delphi practical) and the explanation was extremely helpful.